# history.go(-1) does not go back to previous page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm working on a web system which is implemented in asp.net. I'm developing a search page which works as follow.
title_search2.aspx -> title_search2_result.aspx -> title_info.aspx

Now I want to go back to title_search2_result page when the back button is pressed in title_info page. I do it using history.go(-1). As a result, I'm always going back to title_search2 page.
I don't know why it skips title_search2_result page.

```
title_search2.aspx.cs
public void SearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e){ // when search button is pressed
    ...
    Response.Redirect("./title_search2_result.aspx?" + "searchKey=" + sSearchKey + "&searchType=" + checkedNo.Value + "&megaOnly=" + megaOnly.Value + "&freeOrPurchased=" + freeOrPurchased.Value + "&from=0&stb=" + sSettopId + "&settopMAC=" + sSettopMac);
    ...
}

title_search2_result.aspx.cs
private void SetTitleAttribute(TitleListSortWebServiceRoot titleRoot)
{
    ...
    foreach (TitleHeaderData titleHeader in titleHeaderAry)
    {
        string titleStr = "";
        HtmlAnchor titleAnchor = (HtmlAnchor)this.Page.FindControl("title_choice_" + ti);
        ...
        string HRef = "title_info.aspx?source=" + Constants.ID_TITLE_LIST_SOURCE_TYPE +
                    "&categoryID=" + titleHeader.categoryID + "&serviceID=" + titleHeader.serviceID +
                    "&titleUri=" + titleHeader.uri + "&sort50on=" + sort50on +
                    "&tlPageNum=" + pageNum + "&catParent=" + catParent + "&sortType=" + sortType +
                    "&isAll=" + isAll.ToString().ToLower() + "&recommendCount=0";

        titleAnchor.HRef = HRef;

    ...
}

title_search2_result.aspx
...
<a id="title_choice_0" runat="server" class="spacer">
...


title_info.js
function BackNavigation() {
    history.go(-1);
}
```

Comment: looks like a POST to get to title_search2_result?  (I see a redirect there...) That wouldn't be added to history...

Comment: You could set window.location instead. So BackNavigation(URLstring) { location.href = URLstring; } or the new location.assign(URLstring);  (OR use an Ajax post and do that on the callback... instead of redirect)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think that's the reason why it's not working.